# Checking a cell in pandas for 0, with different types of cell content

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm trying to do an if where I check whether a cell is 0, the problem is that sometimes the cell will have a float, an array or just a 0.

I've done

```
if df.iat[i,df.columns.get_loc('B')] == 0:
     print('something')
```

that gives me an error when there is an array:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

To try and solve that I tried:

```
if df.iat[i,df.columns.get_loc('B')].all() == 0:
     print('something')
```

which arises the error

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'all'*, when the content of the cell is a float

Any ideas how can I work around this issue?

Comment: what do you want to return when it's an array?

Comment: False, so only when it is 0 I want it to be True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because column "B" contains values of different types, you'll need to check for data type first before evaluating if the value is equal to some value. So for example, if `df.iat[i,df.columns.get_loc('B')]` is equal to `[1,2]`, then

```
df.iat[i,df.columns.get_loc('B')] == 0
```

is equivalent to `[1,2] == 0` which doesn't make sense.

You can check the data type first before checking if it's equal to 0 or not.

```
x = df.iat[i,df.columns.get_loc('B')]
if isinstance(x, (int,float)) and x == 0:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Also, if you want to do the same check on the entire column (assuming you want to create a boolean list), you can use a list comprehension where you do a check the data type as well as if it's equal to 0 or not:

```
out = [True if isinstance(x, (int,float)) and x==0 else False for x in df['B']]
```

You can assign it to a column as well:

```
df['zeros'] = out
```